# Php uploaded file unique name issue

Tags: php, mysql

Well, I've a html Upload form which process by .php file (uploader.php). It's a multiple file uploaded code.

So when it's upload, all files are go to upload directory with their individual file name. Like: abc.jpg, abc2.jpg etc.

But If someone upload a file with same name then it's ovrwrite the existing file. So that I need a unique name for the uploaded file. Is there any way to rename the file with unique random name. Like: 12545454.jpge, 234324324.jpge, 323453253.jpg etc..

**Php Code:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
$number_of_file_fields = 0;
$number_of_uploaded_files = 0;
$number_of_moved_files = 0;
$uploaded_files = array();
$upload_directory = dirname(__file__) . '/uploaded/'; //set upload directory


/**
 * we get a $_FILES['images'] array ,
 * we procee this array while iterating with simple for loop
 * you can check this array by print_r($_FILES['images']);
 */
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['images']['name']); $i++) {
    $number_of_file_fields++;
    if ($_FILES['images']['name'][$i] != '') { //check if file field empty or not
        $number_of_uploaded_files++;
        $uploaded_files[] = $_FILES['images']['name'][$i];
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i], $upload_directory . 
$_FILES['images']['name'][$i])) {
            $number_of_moved_files++;
        }

    }

}
echo "Number of File fields created $number_of_file_fields.<br/> ";
echo "Number of files submitted $number_of_uploaded_files . <br/>";
echo "Number of successfully moved files $number_of_moved_files . <br/>";
echo "File Names are <br/>" . implode(',', $uploaded_files);
}
?>
```

Comment: I just want to rename the uploaded file name with unique random number.

Comment: you create, but then don't use  $image_named_uniq

Comment: [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php)

Answer (score 3):

Use [uniqid()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) . It is made for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can concat `time();` and `session_id()` or `uniqid()` as suggested by wormhit is also very good idea  against name of each file.

Use The below code:

```
<?php
$target_path = "images/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
//$upload_directory = ''.uniqid().'_'.dirname(__file__) . '/uploaded/'; //set upload directory

$uploaded_file="".$upload_directory ."/".uniqid()."_".$_FILES['images']['name'][$i]."";

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i],$uploaded_file)) {
            $number_of_moved_files++;
        }
?>


<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
$number_of_file_fields = 0;
$number_of_uploaded_files = 0;
$number_of_moved_files = 0;
$uploaded_files = array();
$upload_directory = dirname(__file__) . '/uploaded/'; //set upload directory


/**
 * we get a $_FILES['images'] array ,
 * we procee this array while iterating with simple for loop
 * you can check this array by print_r($_FILES['images']);
 */
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['images']['name']); $i++) {
    $number_of_file_fields++;
    if ($_FILES['images']['name'][$i] != '') { //check if file field empty or not

        $uploaded_file="".$upload_directory ."".uniqid()."_".$_FILES['images']['name'][$i]."";

        $number_of_uploaded_files++;
        $uploaded_files[] = $_FILES['images']['name'][$i];
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$i],$uploaded_file)) {
            $number_of_moved_files++;
        }

    }

}
echo "Number of File fields created $number_of_file_fields.<br/> ";
echo "Number of files submitted $number_of_uploaded_files . <br/>";
echo "Number of successfully moved files $number_of_moved_files . <br/>";
echo "File Names are <br/>" . implode(',', $uploaded_files);
}
?>
```

Comment: Yes !@Vikas Umrao It's a nice idea.!

Comment: @Vikash Umrao How do i rename the original file name with time() ?

Comment: Replace this $upload_directory = ''.uniqid().'_'.dirname(__file__) . '/uploaded/'; //set upload directory from your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
 $ext = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $newfilename = substr( sha1(uniqid (rand())), 0, 10). '.'.$ext;
```